# In a relational db, should a "parent table" have a reference to a "child table" or the opposite, does it matter?

Tags: java, mysql, database, jpa, database-design

I need to implement some configuration architecture for our software.
There is a `Configuration` table, and there are `ConfigurationProductA` and `ConfigurationProductB` extending Configuration.

Usually, I choose to add a foreign key on the children, referencing `Configuration`, but my reason is not the good one. It's because I'm using Hibernate/Jpa and can (easily) do:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="ConfigurationProductA")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "conf_id")
public class ConfiguratioProductA extends Configuration{/*...*/}
```

What are the pros and cons of referencing a child from the parent? What is the best practice?

Comment: Define "parent" & "child" table. A FK is a column set whose values must appear elsewhere as FK/UNIQUE. When that's declared & not implied by other declarations, declare it.

Answer (score 3):

It depends on the type of relationship between parents and children:

- Assuming that a child has only one parent, and that a parent might have multiple children, then that's a one-to-many relationship: you want to store the parent id in the child.
- If a child may have multiple parents, and a parent may have multiple children, then it is a many-to-many relationship. In that case, the canonical approach is to have a additional entity, called a junction table (or a bridge table) to store the parent/child relations.

Comment: So, when will you store the child in the parent? never?

Comment: @Upsilon42 In the database? Never. --- In the `@Entity`? Depends on how you want to find the children.

Comment: @Upsilon42: if a child has multiple parents but each parent has only one child... which does not seem like a reasonable "parent/child" relationship.